# How to apply SSL certificate to .NET 5 api?

Tags: .net-core, ssl-certificate

I've read other similar answers but they either use IIS, talk about self-signed certificates or don't fill the purpose at all.

I'm trying to create a simple web API that will be hosted in a Windows machine with SQL Express using .NET 5.

I'm able to create a self-signed certificate and use that during development, but this will be hosted in a client's machine and they probably have a SSL certificate. In the past, with web applications that run only in localhost I did something like this:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder ( string [] args ) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults( builder =>
                {
                    builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    builder.UseKestrel(options => {
                        if ( ServerConfiguration.ShouldUseHttps() )
                        {
                            options.Listen( IPAddress.Any, 6050, listenOptions =>
                             {
                                 listenOptions.UseHttps( Path.Combine( "Certificates", "cert.pfx" ), CertificatePassword );
                             } );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            options.Listen( IPAddress.Any, 6050 );
                        }
                    } );
                } );
```

Where cert.pfx is my self-signed certificate. I would ship that certificate with the software, and tell the client to install it, then they can use HTTPS and the browser would trust the certificate. Probably enough for a localhost application, but not for an exposed API.

So let's say the client has bought an SSL certificate and I want my .NET application to use that certificate, that will be installed on the same machine as my application. How can I accomplish that?

Right now, I've just deployed my application in another computer, without any certificates or anything else, but of course I get errors of type "The SSL certificate can't be trusted" (in postman for example).

If the client doesn't buy an SSL certificate, can we use a self-signed certificate?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't configure your endpoints in code. Instead, configure them in your appsettings.json file, as described in [the Kestrel documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#replace-the-default-certificate-from-configuration). You can configure just one endpoint, or multiple.

Here's an example configuration that has an HTTP and HTTPS endpoint, with the certificate from a pfx file with a password:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
          "Password": "<certificate password>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation shows different configurations for the certificate, like a .pem and key file (like you get from Let's Encrypt, for example) or using the Windows certificate store.

This way, if the client gets their own cert, it's just a matter of updating the appsettings.json.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So I should get a cert from let's encrypt for example, install it and then setup like that?

Comment: That's one way you can do it. It's up to you.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it this way. I'll approve your answer tomorrow. Have a great day!